# Casting Session variable - ViewBag MVC4 - Casting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

New to programming, I am tring to get the value of one cell from a table using c# in asp.net MVC; here what I am trying:

```
 DALEntities db = new DALEntities();
  var duration = db.MyTable.Where(c => c.Day == date && c.ID == id).Select(c => c.Duration);
            Session["duration"] = duration;
```

to get the data to a view I use, in the controller:
            var temp = Session["duration"];
            ViewBag.Duration = temp;

and in the view:

```
 @ViewBag.Duration
```

I get

```
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could call a `.First()` at the end to eagerly execute the query and get the single result matching this criteria:

```
var duration = db
    .MyTable
    .Where(c => c.Day == date && c.ID == id)
    .Select(c => c.Duration)
    .First();
```

Be careful though because if there are no records matching your `.Where()` clause, the `.First()` extension method will throw an exception. In this case you might consider using the `.FirstOrDefault()` method.

I also very strongly recommend you to learn [basic LINQ](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) **before** learning Entity Framework and mostly **before** learning ASP.NET MVC. Otherwise you will be struggling a lot with ASP.NET MVC. I also recommend to people learning separate frameworks in isolation without mixing them. Once you are familiar with them you could mix in one project.

Comment: `First` won't throw an exception if there are multiple results; `Single` will.

Comment: @DStanley, `First` will throw an exception if there are 0 matching records. `Single` will throw an exception if there are 0 or more than 1 matching records. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer as I wrongly initially stated that `First` will throw an exception if multiple records are found.